# getting error in applying filtering in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a very basic question in c++ and opencv.
I want to apply Bilateral filter into my image but I get this error which shows that I have not allocated memory!

"Unhandled exception at 0x7620c41f"

now this is my question:
should I allocate memory even when I have not defined any pointer?

```
for ( int i = 1; i < MAX_KERNEL_LENGTH; i = i + 2 ){
    bilateralFilter ( result, dst, i, i*2, i/2 );
}
```

this is the type of result and dst that are both defined as a Mat...

```
cv::Mat result = Mat(height, width, CV_32FC1, distances);
cv::Mat dst = Mat(height,width, CV_32FC1, distances);
```

when I debug it I put the redpoint in for line and when I step into the next line I get the error :(

sorry that My question is basic and thanks in advance.

Comment: hmm, what's "distances" ?  you seem to have 2 mats, that point to the same data

Comment: it is not the problem I guess, because what I was trying to do here was just defining a Mat called dst. I can change this line to this:

cv::Mat dst;

Comment: ah, ok. ignore me then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but you are not calling the function `cv::bilateralFilter()` correctly.

According to the available documentation, the prototype is:

```
void cv::bilateralFilter(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int d, 
                         double sigmaColor, double sigmaSpace)
```

with the additional conditions that `src` is an 8-bit, 1 or 3-channel image and `dst`has the same type and size as `src`.

In the code that you provide, there are several issues:

- `src` (your variable `result`) does not seem to have been initialized with any image data (but maybe that's a question artifact)
- your `src` matrix is a 32 bits, 1 channel image instead of an 8 bits, 1 channel. You need to **convert your matrix to the proper data type** beforehand, e.g., `result.convertTo(src, CV_8U, aProperScalingFactor);`. The scaling factor is required to ensure that you have 8 bits data in the range [0,255];
- as pointed out in the comment by @berak, you're somehow trying to define two matrices  that share the same underlying data storage. The behaviour of the fnction `cv::bilateralFilter()` does not mention in-place processing capabilit ythough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer...I came up with a questions..
--when I am defining a MAt which is going to be filled with some result(as an output of a called function), is it important that how this Mat is made? sine it will be filled with some new data..

Comment: If you want to just allocate a Mat (e.g., to store the result of a filter), you can simply use the method cv::Mat::create(). In your case, it would be: dst.create(result.size(), CV8U). This pattern is implemented by many OpenCV filters, so usually you just declare you variable and pass it to the filtering function.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry because of my bad english